# iPhone SDK: Interface Builder label font, only shows when editing label

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have tried this on a few installations of the 3.1.3 SDK.

When I add a label to my view, I would like to change the font to something like Futura.  I know how to change the font, but, for some reason, it does not show that it is changed.  ONLY when I edit the label by double clicking, do I see my new font.  And, this is the only time that I do get to see the new font, is when editing the label.

Why does this happen?  How can I change the font of my labels, and have it show up?  Why would I care to have the font changed when I edit the label?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few system fonts installed on the iPhone.  So when you try to use a non standard font, ala Future, it will not work, because that is no installed on the iPhone.