# How to add custom font in .xib?

Tags: ios4, uifont

I added a custom font in `info.plist`.But it worked only when programmatically changed.it doesn't change when tried through interface builder  by changing the object attribute section. for example i used `UILabel` then i choose the custom font in the attribute section but it did not change the font style.

install the `"Harrowprint"` font by double clicking the file and also add it in my project resource file.

[image]

thanks in advance,

Senthilkumar

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way, but there are some attractive work arounds.

[Using custom fonts in interface builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284817/using-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder)