# Can I include the custom fonts to XIB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios5

In my iPhone App, I need custom fonts.

I know how to include it through info.plist and programmatically, but can I have the fonts in the XIB file?

Where can I set the custom fonts as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284817/using-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the custom fonts from there, instead of that, you have to create an IBOutlet and add the font programmatically

Answer (score 4):

when we edit text in xib,custom Fonts appear, but at runtime it's not get applied.