# iOS does not support Ahmaric language character

Tags: ios, fonts

I am new to objective c. I am working on keyboard for Amharic language. But i am facing some problem, iOS doese not suport Amharic language character. When I assign these Amharic language character (ወርትብቹኢኦፕ ) to my label title or button title it become boxes. I dont know that how to solve this issue. Help me any one please.

Comment: My first guess is that the font used does not support the Amharic language characters. You might want to add a font to you app that does support Amharic character.

Comment: Theres a reference to some Amharic fonts here. http://ethio247.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-read-amharic-and-write-amharic.html . You could add them to your app (assuming they are open-source or buyable)

Comment: Also Id raise a bug with Apple about the lack of support for this language. The more people who ask raises the probability of it being included.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

From [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529609/can-i-include-the-custom-fonts-to-xib) and similar, best solution is:

**You cannot add the custom fonts from there, instead of that, you have to create an IBOutlet and add the font programmatically**

so:
1)Drag and drop ttf font file in your resources folder 
and add in info.plist:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array>
     <string>AmharicFontFile.ttf</string>
  </array>
```

or by clicks in Xcode:

I)in plist file (projectView, click on info.plist)

II)create new row called "Fonts provided by application"

III)than create new item, ie:

```
 item0 |  AmharicFontFile.ttf
```

than in code:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Amharic" size:20];
[label setFont:font];
```

where "Amharic" is font name (not just filename without extension, but could be the same)

Comment: specific font file, probably you need a license for it, or just google "free Amharic ttf" than install it and see how it looks on mac, than you could try in ios sim or device.

Comment: The OP is having issues with Xcode (i.e. Interface Builder) and his question doesn't appear to be "how do I embed a custom font in my app".

Comment: I think in IB it looks ok, because it uses mac resources, these chars appear well, but when running on device it gives squares.

Comment: ok, edit made, but even if You have that font on Mac, will it be visible on device ?

Comment: @Laila, ttf you could try to grab here http://ethiomereja.com/index/geez-ethiopian-amharic-fonts/  I'll try now some of it....

Comment: I can add .ttf font but thier is any possibility that it will solve  my issue i mean when assign these amharic language character to my button and whenever i click on the button the actual text is shown in text view. thanks for giving me your precious time

Comment: @Laila, my bad, it's not so easy, XCode not updating fonts, so I Installed ttf, but this new font not appeared in Interface Builder see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529609/can-i-include-the-custom-fonts-to-xib  for similar question.

Comment: @Laila, answer edited, I suppose it could be done only programaticaly, so try to change from code

Answer (score 0):

Xcode defaults button labels to the system font.  If your system font does not support the glyphs in language X, you need to set the button's font to a font that does.

If no built in font supports language X, then you'll need to license a font that does and include it in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that MacOS supports this language, but iOS does not. if the current font (e.g. the system font) does not have a certain character, it looks for a 'fallback' font that has the desired characters. If iOS doesn't have a localization for this language, it's likely Apple left away the font for this language to save space.

I presume the text looks OK in Interface Builder and in the simulator, but not on the device(1)? Or does it only look right in TextEdit, and both IB and the simulator don't show them right(2)? In either case, you will probably have to license and install a custom font that contains the desired characters and include it with your app.

1) The simulator and IB are both really Mac applications that just pretend to be iOS, so behave differently than a real iOS device. So it could be that they have access to all fonts on your Mac, while on the device there are actually fewer fonts.

2) However, the simulator and IB make some effort to simulate a real iOS device, so if it doesn't work there either, but works in a real Mac app like TextEdit, someone was extra smart and filters the font list.