# How to represent a letter not supported by IOS in swift

Tags: swift, unicode, uifont

I am trying to represent the Amharic letter "ሀ" as this
let letter = "\u{1200}" 
but when I run the app it gives me a question mark. 
any one who knows how to represent unicode characters not supported by IOS in swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to express Strings in Swift using Unicode hexadecimal values (UTF-16)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284538/how-to-express-strings-in-swift-using-unicode-hexadecimal-values-utf-16)

Comment: It `print`s fine in Playground. How are you presenting it to the screen? In a label? as the output of `drawString`? Do you know what font is being used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS does not support Ahmaric language character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697483/ios-does-not-support-ahmaric-language-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rendering of the character is the problem, make sure you use a font that is capable of that character.

If this is no duplicate, it's about the font, not swift or representation in code.