# Custom font in interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I want to install custom font and used in UIlabel from ibterface builder,xcode4.2?I tried the Google ways but its not showing in the Interface builder?

Comment: Refer [using-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284817/using-custom-fonts-in-interface-builder) link.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6620938/1106035) answer. Get helped by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Add the font file in your project and use the following to set the font.

> ```
> self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"yourFontName" size:yourFontSize];
> ```

Comment: still its not  showing in the inteface builder

Answer (score 0):

First save your custom font file in your project folder and then you have to add it to Your_Project_name-Info.plist file which might be located in your **supporting files** folder

1. click on **Your_Project_name-Info.plist**
2. Add new object(array)=>type **Fonts provided by application** on key field.
3. Add an object in that array with **name of your font**

Comment: still its not showing in IB yaar

Comment: why dont u do it programmatically after doin the following steps

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Xcode 4.6, you cannot have Interface Builder display a custom font that it did not already come with. In order to have a label use a custom font you will have to display it programmatically. Which means that you will be unable to use IB to determine how long to make a label or anything like that.